# sqlalchemy check that schema is empty

Tags: python, database, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I want to check that the public schema has no object at all.(Tables, views, functions, operators, data types, domains, triggers and rules)

I know that I can get the tables names and view names and check that they're empty but I haven't found any function for the other types of objects. Is there some way I can check it?

Here's how i've done this for checking tables of the public schema

```
        from sqlalchemy.engine.reflection import Inspector

        def foo():
           inspector = Inspector.from_engine(engine)
           tables = inspector.get_table_names('public')
           print(tables)
```